# Error:(10, 33) error: cannot find symbol class GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i also add dependencies

[image]

But Not Working

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you synced project after adding dependencies ??

Comment: Yes..............

Comment: install support library from the sdk manager!

Comment: Yes i install that

Comment: @JayminBhadani Restart android studio

Comment: Add this in your mainfest `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />`

Comment: Thanks @PiyushKukadiya, i find solution we need to add     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***hello guys i find solution of my own question  We need to to just add
recyclerview dependencies***

[image]